# IIS 6 to IIS 7.5 exporting SSL certificate

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-6, iis-7.5

Our current site is on IIS 6.0 with an EV SSL certificate from GoDaddy (I know - bad choice).

I'm currently in the process of migrating to a new server with IIS 7.5.  I need to keep the same host name so when the switchover is ready I just want to re-IP the servers.

If I export the SSL from IIS 6.0 and import it on the IIS 7.5 server, will this disable the certificate on the IIS 6?  Ideally I'd like to copy the certificate to the new box and then through my hosts file pointing to the new server complete my testing and migration.

GoDaddy support's e-mail response to this, while surprisingly thorough, wasn't clear on that point.  They also suggested that after the certificate was moved to the new server to re-key through their site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting your SSL certificate does not disable your certificate.  It just makes a backup copy of it.  You should be able to export your certificate from your old server and then import it into your new server with no problem.

If you modify your hosts, as you mentioned, it should let you test your certificate as working.